# How to set a default Filter Criteria before users choose one from list in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm trying to build a website for a magazine with Drupal 7. I have to Content Types, Issue and Article. Issue contains the first page of magazine, and Article is for its contents. I have also a Taxanomy Term Field (Issue Number) to relate these two content types.
Then, I made a View with Issue and Artcile. A page, which shows latest Node published as Issue (it means number of items to display is 1 here), and an attachment to show Artciles which related to that Issue (there is no limitation here for items to display). I also add a Filter Criteria which allow users to choose each Issue Number and It works well: Displays latest Issue and its Articles in the bottom.
Now my problem is here:

- Before you choose a specific Issue Number, the view shows ALL of the articles not only which are related to last Issue. I want to find a way to set a Default Filter (last Issue Number) for my articles. I don't want to limit number of items to displays, because for each issue it would be a different number.

I got stock in this for days now so really appreciate your help. ( Also asked this in drupal.stackexchange, but didn't receive any answer!)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a view on your taxonomy term 'Issue Field number', limitting that view to 1, and set order by last created.

Then you attach another view in which you print the articles, thus only showing articles for the last created "Issue"